# Activating hidden sheet within workbook Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a summary sheet called 'Summary' which has a link on it. This link goes to the following sub:

```
Sub WTButton()
Call GoToWorksheet("Wilmington")
End Sub
```

As you can see, this calls another sub called `GoToWorksheet`. It looks like this:

```
Sub GoToWorksheet(strWorksheet As String)
On Error GoTo Err_GoToWorksheet
With Worksheets("Summary")
   If Worksheets(strWorksheet).Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
      Worksheets(strWorksheet).Visible = xlSheetVisible
   End If

   Worksheets(strWorksheet).Activate

End With

Exit_GoToWorksheet:
   Exit Sub

Err_GoToWorksheet:
   MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "GoToWorksheet Error"
   Resume Exit_GoToWorksheet

End Sub
```

I want the sheet to remain hidden until the end user is ready to add data to it. This whole system works great IF the sheet is already visible. If the sheet is hidden, it does not make it visible and it does not activate it.

What am I doing wrong?

LINK TO FILE: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wsv9al410m7kwda/Book1Test.xlsm

Comment: Your `with` block does not appear to be necessary.

Comment: What happens? Just nothing?   Try this instead `If Worksheets(strWorksheet).Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then`
`

Comment: Are your sheets just hidden, or "very hidden"?

Comment: @mr.Reband, if I take out the `with` block, it still does not activate the hidden sheets.

Comment: @TimWilliams, My sheets are just 'hidden', not 'veryhidden'.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I tried the code with the `<>` and it gave me the same results I was getting before -- hidden sheets do not activate.

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the if statement and just always set it to `xlSheetVisible`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did to make things work: I got rid of the `GoToWorksheet` subroutine. I then made the `WTButton` sub look like this:

```
Sub WTButton()
Worksheets("Wilmington").Visible = xlSheetVisible
Worksheets("Wilmington").Activate
Range("A3").Select
End Sub
```

This makes it much more direct [Note: I took over this project from someone else]

Comment: If this solution solved your problem, please consider marking it as the 'accepted' answer for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but should work...

```
Sub GoToWorksheet(strWorksheet As String)
  On Error GoTo Err_GoToWorksheet
  With Worksheets(strWorksheet)
     If .Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
     End If
     .Activate
  End With

Exit_GoToWorksheet:
   Exit Sub

Err_GoToWorksheet:
   MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "GoToWorksheet Error"
   Resume Exit_GoToWorksheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the same thing mine does. I click the link and it stares at me (for sheets that are hidden). Works great for those that are visible.

Answer (score 0):

The `With` is not needed, and it does not test for `xlVeryHidden`

I would write the routine this way:

```
Option Explicit
'This makes sure I find spelling errors

Sub GoToWorksheet(strWorksheet As String)
   On Error GoTo Err_GoToWorksheet 'Should only fail if worksheet name is wrong
   Worksheets(strWorksheet).Visible = xlSheetVisible
   'just make it visible - don't care what state it was in previously
   Worksheets(strWorksheet).Activate
   Exit Sub

Err_GoToWorksheet:
   MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "GoToWorksheet Error"

End Sub
```

and for testing, to discover where exactly the error is, I would comment out all the error handling